# MVC - Mark Multiple Fields invalid in Custom Validation Attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form where users enter their preferred contact method. It has:
 - a radio button where a user selects whether they'd like to be contact by phone or email or either
 - a textbox for the user's email address
 - a textbox for the user's phone number

I have validation via a custom attribute that verifies that if the user selected phone they entered a phone number, if they selected email they entered an email, etc... but it's at a class level on my ViewModel. As such the validation doesn't mark the expected field as invalid.

Is there a way that my IsValid override (or some other method) can mark the child property's value as invalid so I get highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you may take a look at the [following blog post](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/02/24/validationresultmembernames.aspx). If not what can I say other than, well, Data Annotation have limits. And it's exactly because of limitations like this (of course that's just an example but there are many others) that I use [FluentValidation.NET](https://fluentvalidation.net/).

Comment: You're a rock star, thanks for the input. This definitely gets me going!